# How to pass arguments to Laravel factories?

Tags: laravel, factory, laravel-seeding

I have a `users` table and a one-to-zero/one relation with a `businesses` table (users.user_id => businesses.user_id). On my `users` table I have a discriminator which tells me if the user is of type business and therefore I need to have details on the `businesses` table as well.

I want to create my Users with my factory which currently is working and then only create business details where the discriminator points to a business account.

I have three options in my mind:

1. Create from users factory and then using '->each()' do some checks on the discriminator and create a new business user using a the factory. However I cannot pass to the business factory the `user_id` that the user was assigned.
2. First create the users. Then in my Business seeder, retrieve all Users that match a 'business' discriminator. Then for all of these users run a factory that creates the business details. But again, I would have to link somehow the `user_id` of the already create user with the business factory `user_id`.
3. In my business factory, create a new User and retrieve the id, thus making the link between `users.user_id` and `business.user_id`. However I am using a random generator for `user.user_type` so even if I have the `businesses` table filled it might be for users that have the discriminator as 'personal'.

Is there another way? Can I pass arguments from my Seeder to the factory?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The attributes you pass to the `create` function will be passed into your model definition callback as the second argument.

---

In your case you don't even need to access those attributes, since they'll automatically be merged in:

```php
$business = factory(App\Business::class)->create();

factory(App\User::class, 5)->create([
    'business_id' => $business->id,
]);
```

Adapt this to your needs.

Comment: How could I have missed that. I watched the Laracast lesson and I know remember about setting stuff myself. Of course it was in the documentation as well: http://laravel.com/docs/master/testing#model-factories. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Cristian's link looks outdated now, for 5.4 see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database-testing#using-factories & scroll down to 'Persisting Models'

Comment: what about like this?
```php
$student->assignRole('student');
```
im using spatie/permission

Comment: what if i don't want to merge them? what if i want to use custom parameters to model factories?

Comment: @shotex - If you want custom parameters, why are you using factories? Just create the model yourself: `User::create($attributes)`

Comment: @JosephSilber In my case I would want to pass a $user parameter so I can get its type and according to that, get a random value associated with it.

Comment: Great, the manual puts it like this: You may override attributes on the model by passing an array to the create method.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#persisting-models

Answer (score 10):

My code for adding polymorphic 'Admin' users was:

```php
// run model factory
factory(App\Admin::class, 3)->create()->each(function ($admin) {

    $admin->user()->save(

        // solved: https://laravel.com/docs/master/database-testing#using-factories (Overriding attributes)
        factory(App\User::class)->make([
              'userable_id' => $admin->id,
              'userable_type' => App\Admin::class
        ])
    );
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Robin how can i use the variable inside the factory ? not directly override

Comment: @George Then just use `make()` without the array of custom values for **userable_id** and **userable_type**.

Comment: i want the admin variable to be usable in the User factory, ex `if( $admin->name == 'test'} do something`

Comment: Then you'll need to use the `Admin` class: `$admin = new Admin()`.  Start there and see where it goes.

Comment: is there a way to access the $admin->id inside user factory?

Comment: @vikrant I believe $admin->id works within the Admin factory only. For the User factory, I think you have to hard-code the admin ID.

Comment: make doesn't seem to save the record btw

Comment: thanks this is great and help with my seeds

Answer (score 5):

Send attribute,

```
factory(App\User::class)->create(['businessId' => $businessId]);
```

Retrieve it,

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker, $businessInfo) {
    //$businessInfo['businessId']
});
```